# Monitor vSphere DRS concurrent vmotions count

Tags: monitoring, vmware-vsphere, automation, vmware-vcenter

We are going to enable DRS on the vSphere 5.5 cluster and want to enable email notifications if more than X VMs are migrated simultaneously.

I found that it's possible to send a message when VM is migrated but do not know how to configure alert to trigger only when X VMs are migrating in the same time

Br,
Sergey

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: We had an issue in the past with DRS, when DRS triggered hundreds of VMs to be migrated in the same time. It was when we were running 5.1, now wer are on 5.5 and want to give DRS one more chance

Comment: I'd recommend fixing the issues with DRS.